# Segmentation fault after updating the fields of a class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a few classes that I construct within my main function.  They are each deconstructed after main returns, since they are defined in local variables.  However I have noticed an odd occurance that I would like to avoid.  If I change the memory layout of one of the classes (by adding or changing a field), then recompile only the modified class before linking, I get either a segmentation fault or an invalid pointer (depending on what changes I made to the program).  If I recompile the main file as well, there is no error.

I am fairly certain this happens since when I include the header in my main file, it assumes a certain amount of memory to be allocated for each of the classes, but this value has changed since the main.o was compiled, and therefore it is looking for memory that is not there when it goes to deconstruct the objects as the program closes.

While recompiling the main file isn't an issue at the moment, I am afraid that as the project grows I will be running into this in other files, and recompiling them all each time to avoid errors is undesireable.  Is there a simple way to avoid these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading cdhowie's answer, I started looking into mkdep, however it appears such programs are deprecated, and have been replaced by compiler flags that do the same thing.  I have included the body of my makefile which compiles both the main program (code in srcpath) and the tests (code in testpath) then runs the tests. Two seperate dependency files are created during this, one for main, the other for the tests.

```
src = $(shell cd $(srcpath); find ./ -name "*.cpp")
testsrc = $(shell cd $(testpath); find ./ -name "*.cpp")
obj = $(src:%.cpp=%.o)
testobj = $(testsrc:%.cpp=%.o)
head = $(shell cd $(srcpath); find ./ -name "*.h")
testhead = $(shell cd $(testpath); find ./ -name "*.h")
skip_files = ./main.o

makedep = $(shell $(cpp) $(cflags) -MM -MT '$(patsubst $(srcpath)%.cpp, $(objpath)%.o, $(file))' $(file) >> .depend)
makedeptest = $(shell $(cpp) $(cflags) -MM -MT '$(patsubst $(testpath)%.cpp, $(testobjpath)%.o, $(file))' $(file) >> .dependtest)

all: main Test

Test: .dependtest $(addprefix $(testobjpath),$(testobj))
    @echo "Linking Tests"
    @$(cpp) $(lflags) -o $(testbin) $(addprefix $(testobjpath), $(testobj)) $(addprefix $(objpath), $(filter-out $(skip_files),$(obj)))
    @./$(testbin)

.dependtest: $(addprefix $(testpath), $(testsrc)) $(addprefix $(testpath), $(testhead))
    $(shell rm -f .dependtest)
    $(foreach file,$(addprefix $(testpath), $(testsrc)), $(makedeptest))

$(addprefix $(testobjpath), %.o): $(addprefix $(testpath), %.cpp)
    $(cpp) $(cflags) -c -o $@ $<

main: .depend $(addprefix $(objpath), $(obj))
    @echo "Linking Program"
    @$(cpp) $(lflags) -o $(bin) $(addprefix $(objpath),$(obj))

.depend: $(addprefix $(srcpath), $(src)) $(addprefix $(srcpath), $(head))
    $(shell rm -f .depend)
    $(foreach file, $(addprefix $(srcpath), $(src)), $(makedep))

$(addprefix $(objpath), %.o): $(addprefix $(srcpath), %.cpp)
    $(cpp) $(cflags) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    -rm $(testbin) $(bin) $(addprefix $(objpath),$(obj)) $(addprefix $(testobjpath),$(testobj))

-include .depend
-include .dependtest
```

Answer (score 1):

It's considerably more likely that some class members (such as the constructor and/or destructor) are being inlined and some are not, and each set is going to be using a different offset from the object pointer to find a particular member.

Consider using something like [`mkdep`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mkdep1.html) to generate a makefile with proper source-to-header dependencies, such that changing a header causes all files including that header to be recompiled.

Alternatively, you could opt to keep *all* class member definitions (including constructors, copy constructors, and assignment operators -- nothing should be auto-generated in this case) in the source file for the class, effectively disallowing inlining.  This should be sufficient to prevent this problem in most cases, but it comes at a (slight) performance cost.  (And this won't help you out if you add data members to the class -- thereby increasing the size of objects -- unless you additionally use the [pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom), which adds a level of indirection to all data member accesses.)

Answer (score 1):

No. If the layout of your class changes, you'll need to recompile any unit that uses that class.

Answer (score -3):

Use an IDE instead of compiling at the command line.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but a makefile would serve equally well.  There's nothing magic about IDEs.

Comment: True, I just thought an IDE might be an easier solution for a beginner.

Comment: I am using a makefile on a remote linux platform, that automatically compiles the necessary source before linking, as such, an IDE is an added level of complexity that isn't worth the gain.

Comment: @GodricSeer If your makefile isn't recompiling files that use your classes, then I'd say it's missing a dependency.

Comment: yes, I was making the only dependency for %.o: %.cpp.  Since mkdep isn't available on my distro, I am looking into using g++ -MM to generate a more complete dependency list.